# In Javascript, when using an if statement to compare zero and not false with triple equal signs, why is not false equal to false?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm creating a typing test in Javascript. When the user presses the keyboard button, the typing test begins if zero keys have been pressed previously. If textEnteredLength (keys pressed) is === 0 and !timerRunning is equal to not false. Why does this function run? 0 === not false, is not a true statement, right?

```
    var timerRunning = false;
    
    function start() {
    let textEnterdLength = testArea.value.length;
    if (textEnterdLength === 0 && !timerRunning){
        timerRunning = true;
        interval = setInterval(runTimer, 10);
    }
```

Comment: It's running because zero keys have been pressed and the timer is not running, what do you expect?

Comment: Don't try to read it as English. Comparisons are not distributed across `&&`.

Comment: Did you mean to write `textEnterdLength === 0 && timerRunning !== 0`?

Answer (score 0):

Due to operator precedence, this expression:

```
textEnterdLength === 0 && !timerRunning
```

is equivalent to

```
(textEnterdLength === 0) && !timerRunning
```

The 0 isn't compared against `!timerRunning`, but against `textEnterdLength`.

So, in the end it's

```
if (someBoolean && someOtherBoolean)
```

and if both are true, it'll run.

Comment: Why is textEnterdLength equal to !timerRunning?

Comment: It isn't. They're never compared against each other. The only way they're chained together is across the `&&` operator. `textEnterdLength` is only compared against 0, the number. Then the result of that (which is a boolean) is `&&`d with `!timerRunning`.

Comment: `textEnterdLength === 0 && !timerRunning` compares `textEnterdLength` against 0 and evaluates to a boolean, resulting in `someBoolean && !timerRunning`. `!timerRunning` also evaluates to a boolean, resulting in `someBoolean && someOtherBoolean`. `textEnterdLength` is never compared against `timerRunning` except after the intermediate operations which have reduced the problem to `someBoolean && someOtherBoolean`.